# To print 1 to 25

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, numbers

Expected output:
1 2 3 4 5

10 9 8 7 6

11 12 13 14 15

20 19 18 17 16

21 22 23 24 25

Tried following code:

```
 for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++)
{
if($i%5 ==0)
{ 
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    for($j=($i+5);$j>$i;$j--)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";        
}
else if ($i%5!=0)
{
    echo $i;
}

}
```

Comment: Check your logs, they will contain the actual error message

Comment: if I am changing anything then I am getting this error
     The mysqli error was: Access denied for user    'alpha_fire'@'182.18.173.253' (using password: YES).

Comment: Well there you go then - you don't have access to the database with that username and password from that host. I'm not sure how the error could be any clearer

Comment: so how can i grant access for this user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++)
{
if($i%5 ==0)
{ 
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    for($j=($i+5);$j>$i;$j--)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    $i = $i+5;  
    echo "<br>";    
}
else if ($i%5!=0)
{
    echo $i;
}

}
```